# Quarterfinal #3 Problem 1 $\int_0^{2^{10}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\text{frac}\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

How do we solve $$\int_0^{2^{10}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\text{frac}\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)dx$$ where $\text{frac}(x)$ denotes the fractional part of $x$? This problem came from the MIT Integration Bee 2023 Quarterfinals. I graphed this and realized that we just have a bunch of triangles to calculate the area of, so I thought that the answer is $2^8$. This isn't correct though, as the answer should be $12\cdot2^9$ or $3\cdot2^{11}$. So how do we get the correct answer?

Comment: Why does this have 3 downvotes?

Comment: @Accelerator It's those people who just downvote just to get users mad. Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Deduce
$$
\int_0^{2^{10}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\text{frac}\left(\frac{x}{2^n}\right)dx
=
\sum_{n=0}^{9}2^n\int_0^{2^{10-n}}\text{frac}\left(x\right)dx
+
\int_0^{2^{10}}\sum_{n=10}^{\infty}\frac{x}{2^n}dx
$$
and
use
$$
\int_0^n \text{frac}(x)dx=\frac{n}{2}\quad,\quad n\in \Bbb Z.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! But how did you get the first line?

Comment: Since $x<2^{10}$, you can divide the summation into cases where $\frac{x}{2^n}$ is a positive integer more than 1 or is always less than 1. For either cases, the summation takes a simple form as described above.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarification!